# Sync contacts with Facebook Lite

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook

I've just installed Facebook Lite on my Galaxy A3 with Lollipop and no root. It satisfies all my necessities except for one: the contacts sync, which is present in the full version of Facebook.

I've thought of not uninstalling the full version, but instead using greenify to prevent it from running in the background, so that I can open it sometimes and get contacts to sync, but I wish there was a better solution.

I could not find any specific app to sync contacts because of the restrictions of the new Facebook APIs (in order for them to work properly I should ask all my friends to manually grant permission).

How could I sync my Facebook contacts having just the Lite version of the app running in the background?

Comment: The idea behind using Facebook Lite is that, it is designed for the barebones facebook experience. Its for people with really low data speeds. So I think that's the reason why it doesn't have all the features that the normal app has. As you noted. Facebook changed their API's in May of 2015. So it seems if you want your facebook contacts synced with your phone contacts, You have to use the main facebook app or get all your friends to download one of the other apps and give it permission to share their info.

Comment: Also since you are using a Samsung device. Check under Settings > Accounts. I think there is a facebook option. Unless that changed with the changes as well to the api. But I remember seeing that when I owned the Note 4. That might pull down your facebook contacts and sync them for ya.

Comment: @jer3my thanks, the option is present into settings>account and is already checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with [Social Contact Photo Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.michaelflisar.socialcontactphotosync).